# Determine Kubernetes cluster size

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I am confused in finalize the cluster size for my QA kubernetes deployment which can be used by 150 people. Follwing are the services i need to deploy:
6 Spring boot microservices with 4pods,
1 Angular application with 4 pods

Can anyone help me in finalizing the size?

Comment: Why tags for both Google and IBM Cloud? Pod does not equal pod, it depends on the compute resources behind. And microservices can be small or big.

Comment: This might be [helpful](https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-instance-calculator?fbclid=IwAR3lE6nwDC_eNzPN5GWUgXmn8rtOPb08r2RvkeWu7f6eytvlkb12Pju5cL4) as a starting point. It is an instance calculator for kubernetes

Comment: Did @danyL comment help you to solve your problem?

Comment: Not exactly, but helped me to understand about instance calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managing a Kubernetes cluster is not a one-size-fits-all problem. There are many ways to rightsize your cluster, and it is vital to design your application for reliability and robustness.

Factors which we need to consider when making a decision:

1. High Availability
2. Management Overhead
3. Ease of Scheduling Container
4. Node Auto-Scaling
5. Ease of Maintenance
6. Kubelet Overhead
7. System Overhead
8. Rightsizing Your Nodes

You can use the following to arrive at an optimal figure:

The number of containers per node = Square root of the closest lower perfect square to the total number of containers, provided the number of containers per node doesn’t exceed the recommended value

Number of nodes = Total number of containers / The number of containers per node

Overprovision factor = Number of containers per node * max resource per container / (Number of nodes — Max planned unavailable nodes)

Node capacity = max resource required per container * the number of containers per node + overprovision factor + Kubernetes system resource requirements

Refer to the [document](https://betterprogramming.pub/tips-for-rightsizing-your-kubernetes-cluster-e0a8f1093d8d) for more information.